# How to add an UIImage to UITextView

Tags: image, uiimage, uitextview, addition

I am working on chat message board where I have textView and some fixed number of images. 
I want that when I select an image it should attach at the end of the text and when I press done the text and image should be send to other user. 
Please suggest how to attach an image to UItextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a work around for this, I am creating a UIView and am placing the textview with clear color and a frame for the image, so when the user clicks on the existing images it appears on the image frame, this way it gives a feel that the image and the text they both are in the the textarea.

This doesn't answer the question directly, but it is a workaround with which I am currently making the progress.